# How to Create a water screen with solenoid valve in arduino

Tags: arduino-mega

I want to make a water screen. I will create character with solenoid valve. Sometimes sequential valve will pass to water, sometimes not pass.

And I will create some shape or character.

But I don't know how can I create this character with Arduino.

Do you have any good idea ? Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to [this page](https://cmosgr.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/electric-solenoid-valve/) for the generic actuation (iow Arduino board + relays shield + power supply for the valves), but that leaves one problem open: timing.

To draw something on a wall of water, you need to make sure that the water flows with a known, constant speed (unless your wall is very tall, I would ignore the effect of gravity, if the initial speed is high enough).

Maybe it can be achieved without this extra step, but to play it safe, I'd also add a pump that feeds all the valves.

This will ensure that you will have a known pressure/speed of the water, thus being able to calculate the timing of the valves.

You can use one of the relays to control also the pump.
Notice also that most likely an arduino UNO/Nano or equivalent will not be sufficient, as you will get relatively few lines.

An ArduinoMega2560 or DUE have far more GPIOs.